# Making a JSON object in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to send JSON data to a server from my iOS app. I found a tutorial  on [this link.](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/making-a-post-request-in-swift/)
How should the "obj: AnyObject" look like so that this method can be called:

```
NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(obj: AnyObject, options: NSJSONWritingOptions, error: NSErrorPointer)
```

It doesn't accept Dictionary (even though it is somehow used in the example on the link above) or Array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you have a dictionary like

```
let dictionary = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]
```

To generate your JSON Data using the method you provided you just call it:

```
var jsonGenerationError: NSError?
let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: .PrettyPrinted, error: &jsonGenerationError)
```

You can verify it worked by parsing the generated data:

```
var jsonParsingError: NSError?
let parsedObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: .AllowFragments, error:&jsonParsingError)
```

## Swift 4

```
let dictionary = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: .prettyPrinted)
// Verifying it worked:
let parsedObject = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: .allowFragments)
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that I didn't finish writing the method and the error appeared, even though it was a valid object (in this case dictionary) that I was passing as the first argument.