# How do I convert swift Dictionary to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I'm trying to convert a `[String : String]` (a Swift Dictionary) to `NSDictionary`, for later use on a JSON library that produces a string

```
var parcelDict = ["trackingNumber" : parcel.number,
                  "dstCountry" : parcel.countryCode];

if (parcel.postalService != nil) 
{
    parcelDict["postalService"] = parcel.postalService;
}

var errorPtr: NSErrorPointer
let dict: NSDictionary = parcelDict
var data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options:0, error: errorPtr) as NSData

return NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

but `let dict: NSDictionary = parcelDict` does not work

```
let dict: NSDictionary = parcelDict as NSDictionary

var data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parcelDict as NSMutableDictionary, options:0, error: errorPtr) as NSData
```

All of these examples do not work. They produce the following errors:

[image]

[image]

What's the correct way of doing it?

**Update:**

Code that works

```
var parcelDict = ["trackingNumber" : parcel.number!,
                  "dstCountry" : parcel.countryCode!];

if (parcel.postalService != nil) {
    parcelDict["postalService"] = parcel.postalService;
}

var jsonError : NSError?
let dict = parcelDict as NSDictionary
var data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options:nil, error: &jsonError)
return NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to cast it like this:

```
let dict = parcelDict as NSDictionary
```

Otherwise the Swift Dictionary and NSDictionary are treated almost the same way when using it in methods for ex:

```
func test(dict: NSDictionary) {}

let dict = ["Test":1]
test(dict)
```

Will work completely fine.

---

**After your update**

If you change your Dictionary value type to non optional String then your error will go away.

```
[String:String?] change to -> [String:String]
```

Comment: Your dictionary is not a [String:String] its a [String:String?]

Comment: There isnt really any need to have an optional as value in a Dictionary, unless you want to still have the key which is refering to nothing.

Comment: My suggestion is you just change the value to String instead of String?

Comment: Thanks! Could you update your answer? I will accept it

Comment: Did not work for me in case where I had just filtered a [String:String] dictionary.  Had to iterate over [String:String] dictionary, place into new mutable [NSObject:AnyObject] dictionary to convert.

Answer (score 16):

You can use this easy method

```
let dictSwift = ["key1": "value1", "key1": value2]

let dictNSMutable = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: dictSwift)
```

Enjoy coding!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't don't need to convert it to an `NSDictionary`. Just use:

```
var data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parcelDict, options:0, error: errorPtr) as NSData
```

It's mentioned in this post: [Making a JSON object in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263679/making-a-json-object-in-swift)

**Edit**

From your screenshots I believe your problem lies in the value type in your `parcelDict` Dictionary. I can recreate the error with the following code:

```
let dict = [String: String?]()
let nsDict = dict as NSDictionary // [String: String?] is not convertible to NSDictionary
```

However, using a `String` instead of a `String?` as the value type removes the error.

Therefore, when populating `parcelDict` perhaps you should only add to it values which are not `nil`.