# Why every element in NSDictionary in Swift3 needs to be of type 'NSCopying'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I am converting large project developed in Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.0, but in each and every `NSDictionary` forcing to cast value as `NSCopying`.

What is technical reason behind doing this ?

Is there any way to overcome `NSCopying`for each key value pair in Dictionary ?

[image]

**Example Code**

```
let paramDict:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(objects:[
            currentDoctorDetail!.firstName!,
            currentDoctorDetail!.lastName!,
            "",
            categoryIdstr!.trimCharacter(),
            txtviewAddress!.text!.trimCharacter(),
            clinic_lat!,
            clinic_long!,
            txtCall.text!.trimCharacter(),
            txtEdlieNumber.text!.trimCharacter(),
            currentDoctorDetail!.doctorID!,
            appDel.currentLanguage], forKeys: ["first_name" as NSCopying,
                "last_name" as NSCopying,
                "designation" as NSCopying,
                "category_id" as NSCopying,
                "clinic_address" as NSCopying ,
                "clinic_lat" as NSCopying,
                "clinic_long" as NSCopying,
                "contact_number" as NSCopying,
                "edlie_number" as NSCopying,
                "user_id" as NSCopying,
                "lang" as NSCopying])
```

Comment: `NSMutableDictionary` lacks any type information. Easiest solution to get rid of those casts is to use a native Swift `Array`.

Comment: So , now onwards we need to use Swift Collection types compulsory  ?

Comment: Not compulsory but highly recommended, it supports the strong type system of Swift.

Comment: @vadian : Respect your suggestion, but any way for already developed project using Objective C collection type ?

Comment: Of course you can, but then you have to cast all types "manually" as in your code, that's very annoying. Consider to redesign the collection types. A 1:1 translation from Objective-C to Swift is always bad programming habit and pretty inefficient.

Comment: you should be able to make a swift dictionary and cast it to NSDictionary just fine http://stackoverflow.com/a/29502992/1219956 will be a lot neater than using that `NSMutableDictionary` constructor you are using as well