# What is the difference between these two options for converting Swift Dictionary to NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, swift, dictionary, casting, nsdictionary

In my project I have a dictionary of type `[String: AnyObject]` and am converting it to `NSMutableDictionary` to be compatible with some Objective C code in the project.

I started using the below conversion option (which I've seen as an accepted answer in many stack overflow posts):

```
dictionary as? NSMutableDictionary
```

This works in most cases, but in some instances the result was nil which indicates the dictionary could not be converted to NSMutableDictionary. However, with the exact same values in the dictionary the below conversion successfully results in an NSMutableDictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: dictionary)
```

Why would the first option result in nil when the second one is able to convert without any issues?

You can see here [How do I convert swift Dictionary to NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502878/how-do-i-convert-swift-dictionary-to-nsdictionary) that the first option is the accepted answer, but it does not seem to work in all cases. The second option is also mentioned but does not have as many people agreeing that it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This works in most cases

No, this works not at all.

Unlike **immutable** `NSDictionary` Swift `Dictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` are not related.

You can bridge cast (`as` without `?`) `[String:String]` to `NSDictionary` but you cannot bridge cast nor conditionally downcast (`as?`) it to `NSMutableDictionary`.

The second syntax works because a new instance of `NSMutableDictionary` is created. The Swift dictionary parameter is implicitly bridged to `NSDictionary`

---

The same behavior is also true for Swift `Array` and Foundation `NSMutableArray`

Comment: Thanks for this! At first I was confused but I see that the logic I was using was only getting triggered in very specific scenarios so it looked to be working.